# It is a member of the hidden packageQuickCheck-1.2.0.0, How to load hs file

Tags: haskell, cabal, quickcheck

installed QuickCheck,

i install again  cabal install QuickCheck-1.2.0.0

and load again and has error

Could not find module `Test.QuickCheck.Batch':
It is a member of the hidden package`QuickCheck-1.2.0.0'.

It is hidden package, How to do?

ghc -o tryprog hello.hs -package QuickCheck-1.2.0.0
: cannot satisfy -package QuickCheck-1.2.0.0
    (use -v for more information)

besides this error, how to load .hs file with package quickcheck-1.2.0.0?

added 50 points for this question

I sincerely beg for your help on this loading problem!!

Comment: Are you getting this error trying to build your project with Cabal?

Comment: I load .hs file having this error, not build project with cabal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can hide or expose packages with the `ghc-pkg` command as in `ghc-pkg expose QuickCheck-1.2.0.0` and `ghc-pkg hide QuickCheck-2.4` and etc.

Answer (score 3):

`Test.QuickCheck.Batch` is a quickcheck version 1.x module and you likely installed a more recent, 2.x, version of quickcheck.  As usual, you can find the [documentation on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.4.0.1).

Comment: How to uninstall current version of QuickCheck and install QuickCheck version 1.X

Comment: without remove current version, i install 1.2.0.0

Comment: @MFLDSHasdjfkjssnifferANCLhdisk Use command line options to select a version.  If you have two versions, QuickCheck-2.4 and QuickCheck-1.2.0.0, then use the command-line arguments "-hide-package QuickCheck-2.4 -package QuickCheck-1.2.0.0" with ghc or ghci.

Comment: If it's deprecated, what should we use instead?

Comment: @ThomasAhle Batch is a module, so you should probably identify a particular functionality you desire and post it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [GHC user's guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/packages.html) you use -package when compiling to specify a package name. According to the error you are getting you should specify '-package QuickCheck-1.2.0.0'.

Comment: i tried, but have error too, besides compiling directly, can it be loaded in ghci using :load hello.hs?